# Debugging static library function cpp file in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-libraries

Being new to making/using libraries, I followed a simple tutorial to build a static library in Visual Studio (2022). I made a solution with 2 projects in it. One that builds a library and one that uses the library. It worked. Then I made an independent project / solution to see if I can use this library independently from the original solution/projects. I put the lib file and hpp/cpp file into new separate folders and set these folders in project properties (Additional Include and Library Directories + the .lib file).

Problem: I could use the functions from the library in this new project but when I tried to step into it with the debugger, the cpp file it stepped into was from the original project. (that's what the path showed anyway.) When I renamed the old project and tried again, VS complained that the file directory has changed and asked me to set the path to it. I did set it to the newly made directory with only the hpp/cpp in it and it was fine. I made another new project for using the library and tried the whole thing again and then the debugger simply could not step into the function, it stepped over it.

My questions: what was going on here? how did the debugger find the original cpp file when Im positive I did not set that path anywhere in the new project? and how do I debug a static library then? Is putting the cpp file next to the header in the include directory not enough?

Comment: The path to the source files is added to the debug information for the library when you build it. If you create a release build of the library it will not have debug information and thus can only be debugged on the assembler level (without access to source code).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I see. For now, I would like to create debuggable libraries. So I have to leave the source files where they were when I built the library? Does putting the cpp file nest to the header in the include directory make no difference at all?

Comment: If you want to distribute your library as/with its source code, then users that wish to debug it normally want to compile it themselves as part of their own project/solution, and not use your binaries. If you don't distribute the source, then your users obviously cannot debug it at the source level. It is possible to distribute debuggable binaries, the user will then have to [map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/specify-symbol-dot-pdb-and-source-files-in-the-visual-studio-debugger?view=vs-2022) their source and .pdb locations.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude _If you create a release build of the library it will not have debug information and thus can only be debugged on the assembler level (without access to source code)_ That's actually not the case.  You can still include debug information (and thus build a .PDB file) in release builds but the debugging experience can be a bit weird.

Comment: @PaulSanders True, but not by using the default release-build settings (which is what I meant). And yes, debugging optimized code can always turn out to be a bit tricky.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. For now, I only want the libraries to be debuggable on my own machine. Then, I need to keep the sources in their original directories or if I want to change directories, I need to rebuild the library so the source-paths in the lib file get updated. Or do the "mapping" thing. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes exactly, that's what you need to do.

Comment: @Newline I strongly recommend **not** moving source files around unless you then rebuild the library.  It's by far the easiest way.